# Virtual Machine CPU allocation with multiple virtual cores

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, cpu-usage, hypervisor

I'm rather new to the field and Stack Exchange, but I'll try to make this question not garbage. This has really been bugging me recently, because I'm trying to set up something on a VPS and

The question is, in short: Can a single-threaded process running on a virtual machine with multiple virtual cores utilize the full capacity of the physical machine, if that machine only has a single core?

If that was unclear, I'll try to ask the question with more background and detail below:

Suppose I run a resource-intensive, single-threaded process on a virtual machine. This virtual machine has several virtual cores, but as the process only has a single thread, only one core can be executing it. However, the virtual machine runs on a physical machine with only one core.

Normally, when you have multiple cores but a single thread, only one core will be utilized, and the rest are running idle, right? I'm of two minds about the same in a virtual machine, but can't seem to find any information about such a case. I mean, it's a single thread on multiple cores for the VM, sure, but in the end, the physical machine has just a single core, too. Are the other virtual cores going to be just idling, wasting the physical machine's CPU cycles?

Will the hypervisor be able to cater all of the physical core's capacity for the single-threaded process? Can only some hypervisors do this, or is it a common/rare ability for a hypervisor to be able to do this?

I know it's sort of a bad habit to ask multiple questions at the same time, but I feel like these questions are so related they might as well be asked all at once.

Comment: The question does not appear to agree with itself: "Can a single-threaded process on a VM with multiple... cores utilize..., if the machine only has a single core". Please clarify what you mean in the final section: which machine has only a single core? Clearly not the VM because it has multiple cores according to the previous line, and a single-core host is... odd. I cannot say it is impossible to assign multiple vCores to a VM on a host with a single CPU, but I'd say it is NOT the right thing to do, and likely to cause severe issues it it's possible. Please edit your question to clarify.